# how to make clear colour in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am having a `UIWebView` and I want to make it transperent as I have image in background in the Imageview. I tried `webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` but it didn't work.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work; make sure the webview is not opaque.

```
[myWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myWebView setOpaque:NO];
```

You also have to check that your HTML content does not set a background color for the body tag.

```
body{background-color:transparent;}
```

Comment: Almost taken ad verbatim from the TransWeb Apple sample code project introduction text. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TransWeb/Introduction/Intro.html